# How to implement D3 donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[image: Design]

How to implement this donut chart using D3.js? Someone please help me.

I tried below code, but I'm having issues with corner radius and that grey arc in the design:

Javascript:

```
var dataset = {
  apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(dataset.apples))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc);
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

jsfiddle.net/gregfedorov/qh9x5/9

Comment: Please try something before asking how something should be implemented. There are many d3 examples for donut charts. Try and modify those

Comment: I tried. but i am having issues with corner radius and that grey arc in the design.i tried this too. and tried modifying too. http://jsfiddle.net/gregfedorov/qh9x5/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First define data:

```
var dataset = [{
  color: "red",
  value: 11
}, {
  color: "blue",
  value: 20
}, {
  color: "yellow",
  value: 12
}, {
  color: "transparent",//transparent for the gray part
  value: 22
}];
```

define arc for the gray part:

```
var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 18)
  .outerRadius(radius - 13);
```

define arc for the other color donut part:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 20)
  .outerRadius(radius - 10);
```

Now make the gray donut in the background like this:

```
var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
  .data(pie([{
    color: "gray",
    value: 1
  }]))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc1);
```

Now make the colored donut part (there will be a part which has color `transparent` in dataset which will show the gray donut behind) idea is to superimpose one donut chart over the other.

```
var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "foreground")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc);
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/gsL46ewn/)

Comment: Thanks Cyril. The main issue as i mentioned in the above comment is of making the corners of that red and green round. Can you help me with that? @Cyril

Comment: Rounded got it this far http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3Ly934g0/ using stroke-linecap="round"